# svnnotify occasionally produce garbage

Tags: linux, svn

I run [svnnotify](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.79) from a Subversion post-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
RECEIVERS="\
        -x medical@example.com=patients/ \
        -x design@example.com=gui/ \
        -x devel@example.com=trunk/haxe"
NOTIFIER=/usr/bin/svnnotify
if [ -x "$NOTIFIER" ]; then
        "$NOTIFIER" \
        --repos-path "$1" --revision "$2" --with-diff \
        --set-sender software@example.com --user-domain example.com \
        $RECEIVERS $3
fi
```

Which mostly works fine, but occasionally the diff gets corrupted, in the sense that it contains a short block of something that looks like memory corruption:

```
X‚ö·”Î·ð™Ù¿íù·”Î·d‚ö·ôÏú· €ö·  €œÙ¿ætù·”Î·.¸ö·                    ”Î·
```

I have tried giving the option `--encoding ISO-8859-1` to svnnotify, but still see the corruption.

I am on a Debian Lenny system using libsvn-notify-perl 2.79-1.  Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are diffing a binary file inadvertantly.